# Are these questions grammatically correct? Present Simple

Tags: british-english

The sentence: He gets up at seven every morning. 
Why do we can't ask "When does he get up every morning?" and can "When does he get up at seven?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider the questions and answers in the following way.

> Q: **When** does he get up?
>   A: He gets up **at seven**.
>
> Q: **How often** does he get up at seven?
>   A: He gets up at seven **every morning**.

Answer (score -1):

"When does he get up every morning" is correct but the second one seems incorrect. You can also say "When does he get up IN THE MORNING?" For the second sentence,  "When does he get up at seven?" it doesn't make sense. You can use 2 question marks to make it correct. Example - "When does he get up? At seven? " or you can say "Does he get up at seven?" I suggest you to use "seven o'clock" instead of just "seven". PS - I'm not expert in English, it will be better if you wait for other's answers.

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer.

Comment: As I said first one is correct. But second one "When does he get up at seven?" it doesn't make sense. You can use 2 question marks to make it correct. Example - "When does he get up? At seven? " or you can say "Does he get up at seven?" I suggest you to use "seven o'clock" instead of just "seven". PS - I'm not expert in English, it will be better if you wait for other's answers.

Comment: Well, if you edit your question to include your comment I think it improves. Generally ELU doesn't like one-liner answers. They prefer answers which provide a convincing argument or examples.

Comment: "When does he get up at seven?" is fine after a statement such as "Ben likes to lie in as a rule, but on certain days he needs to be up at seven".